# bubble sorting strings through pointers

Tags: c

I am revising my concepts of programming and came across this sorting strings through pointers program

I am receiving the following error :
array subscript is not integer. 
here is my code :

```
                 #include <stdio.h>
                 #include <string.h> 
                 int main()
                {
                 char buffer[100];

                 char *p[10];
                 int n;

                 printf(" Input the number of strings");
                 scanf("%d \n",&n);

                 int i=0;
                 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                 {
                 gets(buffer);
                 *p[i]=(char *)malloc(strlen[buffer]+1);
                  strcpy(*p[i],buffer);
                  }
                  char *temp;
                  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                  {
                  if(strcmp(*p[i],*p[i+1])>0)
                  {
                  *temp=*p[i+1];
                  *p[i+1]=*p[i];
                  *p[i]=*temp;

                   }
         }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Always give all the info you had, and reduce your problem to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is the error?

Comment: Came across it where? `strlen` is a function, not an array. Whoever wrote this clearly never actually tested it.

Comment: Also, please compile your code with all warnings enabled and deal with those, **before** you ask for help.

Comment: It's probably also a Very Bad Idea to learn C by reading code written by someone who uses `gets()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 *p[i]=(char *)malloc(strlen[buffer]+1);
                  strcpy(*p[i],buffer);
```

it should be

```
 p[i]=malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
                  strcpy(p[i],buffer);
```

Or even shorter (using a function defined in POSIX.1):

```
 p[i]=strdup(buffer);
```

Comment: We are in C, so the explicit (char*) conversion is unneccessary and a bad habit, easily leading to hiding errors from the compiler. Never tell it to shut the hell up.

Comment: @PaulR ya i noted that and by that time it was edited. anyway thankyou

Comment: Hm, perhaps add that`strdup()` is a standard non-standard function everyone should have in their toolbox?